# aspherical manifolds of infinite asymptotic dimension

Tags: reference-request

I know that G. Yu asked the question whether the universal cover of a closed aspherical manifold has finite asymptotic dimension in his Annals paper published in 1998. Was this question asked before?

Comment: About which definition of *asymptotic dimension* are we talking? The only one I know is a quasi-isometry invariant and so every compact manifold has asdim = 0.

Comment: I meant the universal cover of  the compact manifold, of course. For some reason, people forget "universal cover" and I got used to this bad habit.  

Comment: Is your question about the existence of a closed aspherical manifold whose universal cover has infinite asymptotic dimension? Or just the historical issue of when this question was first asked?

Comment: I know the answer about existence. I proved it, the paper is in the arXiv: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1103.3873. I wanted to know if anybody before G. Yu formulated the question. I needed the answer for that paper. 